# Why type parameter <K,V> required in Entry<K,V>?

Tags: java, generics

In `java.util.Map`(as shown below), type parameters `<K, V>` of `Entry` are over shadowing type parameters `<K, V>` of `Map`.

```
interface Map<K,V> {
      ......
      interface Entry<K,V> {
           .....
      }
}
```

`class DblyLinkList` from [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/JavaCollections/DblyLinkList.java) has following innerclass `DListNode` that does not require overshadowing type parameter `T`.

```
public class DblyLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
     .......
     class DListNode {
          private T item;
        private DListNode prev;
        private DListNode next;

        DListNode(T item, DListNode p, DListNode n) {
            this.item = item;
            this.prev = p;
            this.next = n;
        }
      }
      ......
}
```

Can you please help me understand the reason for overshadowing type parameters of `Map`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interfaces defined inside a class or interface are static, which means they don't have access to the generic parameters of their parent class. So `Entry` needs the `K` and `V` from its parent.

In contrast, the `DListNode` is an inner-class of `DblyLinkList<T>` and so does have access to the generic type `T` - it actually contains a reference back to its containing class too.

Note, if the `DListNode` was defined as `static class` (which is how I would define it), it would no longer be an inner class and so not have access to its parents generic parameters - and so would need to be `DListNode<K,V>` too.

Comment: inside a class? how can one define `interface` inside a `class`? read your first line

Comment: Of course you can define an interface inside a class. In your case, it's defining an interface inside an interface, but that's fine too, and all the same reulse apply (except the access modifier is different by default).

Comment: One supplementary question, `static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {.. }` has a construcctor. I learnt that `static class` is not instantiable. Can you please clarify the reason for having a constructor `Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {..}`?

Comment: "*I learnt that `static class` is not instantiable*" where'd you learn that?  You can certainly instantiate a `static` class, just like any other class.  In the same file, you'd say `new Node<>(...)`, from another file you'd say `new OuterClass.Node<>(...)`.  Or, if you `import OuterClass.Node;` you can say `new Node<>(...)` from another file too.

Comment: @dimo414 Can you declare a outer `static class` and then instantiate? I think you are talking about nested static class.

Comment: The top-level class in a file cannot be `static`, it won't compile.  Classes inside other classes can be `static` (and instantiated anywhere) or instance classes (and can only be constructed in the context of a containing class instance).

Comment: @dimo414 OK. Can I say that nested class(say `Node`) that implements nested interface must be static? For example: `static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K, V>{..} `

Comment: That's fine, but there's no requirement that it be `static`.